# How can I show users a website without having to re-direct them?

Tags: html, web, hyperlink, popup

Is there a way where  someone clicks on a link, it loads up a pop up thats a simple website, without having to re-direct the user to another tab or app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the site in a popup:

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://YOURSITEHERE.com','popup','width=600,height=600')">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: oh wow thought  there would be more to it,  thanks, so this will enable an interactive site within a pop up?

Comment: @NOCi Yes, it will enable and display a fully active site in the popup! Good luck with your project!

Comment: nice, I have one more question, instead of making this happen through a button click,  can it be done through a link which opens the pop up? so i can the paste the link to other places and have users click the link for the pop up to open.

Comment: I am not sure about that... I tried searching to see if that is possible, but found nothing useful... Sorry!